# After I've plugged my phone into a computer to upload photos, can people see the photos I did not upload even after I unplugged my phone?

Tags: file-upload, iphone, usb

I plugged my phone into a computer at work to upload photos using a USB, then unplugged it. I only uploaded the photos I needed, however, could they somehow see the photos I didn't upload on the computer even when I unplugged the USB after I was done? If it helps, my phone is an iPhone 5s, and I used iTunes to upload these photos off of my phone into a folder on the computer.

Answer (score 4):

### Are you using Microsoft Windows?

If so, yes, it's possible, but...

Let's say you connect your iPhone to your computer. If you view the photos on your iPhone in Windows Explorer, then you will have **thumbnail remnants** for *all* viewed images. These remnants are stored in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\` as `thumbcache*.db`

And yes, **this feature is enabled by default.** You will have to delete the various thumbcache files. Keep in mind that deleting files doesn't necessarily remove them.

If there are compromising photos of you which were viewed in Explorer, such as **IMG_1033.JPG** which *shows Mark Buffalo in a drag*, then you'll want to [take extra steps](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/110079/how-to-completely-remove-all-traces-of-a-file-in-windows-7) to deleting them to ensure that this secret goes to the grave with you.

Comment: I was indeed using Microsoft Windows. These photos that I would rather not anyone see, I did not import to any folders, nor click on. I simply scrolled by them. Could these still be considered thumbnail remnants even though I did not do any of those?

Comment: If you opened the folder and browsed the images before transferring to the computer, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Could they see the content of the files? Likely no. But anti-virus software is typically configured to scan files when media is connected, so it is possible that the system inventoried the files and file names.

Comment: If the OS recognized it as an external drive would it not attempt to index it and create thumbnails? Windows seems particularly intent on creating thumbnails in my past experiences.

Comment: @Dave Depends on the OS. As the OS was not specified, I was giving a generic answer.

Comment: On Windows, thumbnails will be stored in Explorer's cache.